# How can I make this branchless? (Avoiding log(0))

Tags: c#, math, branchless

I have to calculate the function f(x)= x log2(x) branchlessly, defined at 0 as f(0)=0.
The problem is that c#'s `Math.Log2(x)` returns negative infinity for `x=0` and `0*NegativeInfinity=NaN`.

Can I write this branchlessly?

```cs
List<int> list = GetList();
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] != 0)
        size += list[i] * Math.Log2(list[i]);
}
```

A subproblem of this might be doing the branchless version of:

```cs
int x = 0;
int y;

if (x == 0)
    y = 2; // This can be any integer as long as it's positive
else
    y = x;
```

I'm new to the concept of branchless code so I couldn't adapt any of the famous branchless code techniques to this problem.

Comment: Branchlessness is really something done in assembly language, since that's where the branches are observed by the CPU. "Branchless" code in high-level languages frequently fail to correspond to branchless code at the CPU level. For example, there's still a branch in your `for` loop. That said, you could use `Math.Max(x, 1)`. But really, the answer is to use `BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount` to avoid floating point entirely.

Comment: @jdweng Internally `Where` is going to use a `switch` statement and a `if`, so that's not really branchless. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,44b8532e11187695

Comment: int size = list.Where(x => x != 0).Select(x =>  x * Math.Log2(x)).Sum();  or int size = list.Select(x =>  (x == 0) ? 0 : x * Math.Log2(x)).Sum();

Comment: Techically, if you want to make code shorter, you can put `x * Math.Max(double.MinValue, Math.Log2(x))`: the `if` will be hidden, it'll be in `Min`

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, `Math.Max(x,1)` is probably the simplest way to do this and exactly what I was looking for!